# Div taking up full width of page

Tags: html, css, hover

I've implemented a hover state that overlays text when a div is hovered.

Here is the code -

```css
.desktop-image {
  position: relative;
}

.img_description {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .7s, visibility .7s;
}

.desktop-image:hover .img_description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="images" class="misma">
  <div class="desktop-image">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <p class="img_description">This image looks super neat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-image-misma">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

**The problem**
When I inspect the page I notice that the div `.desktop-image` is taking up the full width of the screen (see pic).

[image]

**Question** 
How can I make this div wrap to the size of the actual image, so that the hover state is ONLY implemented when that image is hovered, as opposed to when anywhere within the *blue section* is hovered.

Thanks

Comment: Please take one parent div for img tag so img not cover full div.

Comment: I can't as the parent is being used for a different aspect of the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `div`'s are defined with `display: block`, meaning that they will take the entire available width.

You can specify that `.desktop-image` will be `display: inline-block;` and you will get the wanted result.

My suggestion to you is to use **semantic** HTML, there are 2 element that are dedicated to what you trying to achieve [figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) & [figcaption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption).

Added an example with them.

```css
.desktop-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.desktop-image img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img_description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .7s, visibility .7s;
}

.desktop-image:hover .img_description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="images" class="misma">
  <div class="desktop-image">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <p class="img_description">This image looks super neat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-image-misma">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  </div>

  <figure class="desktop-image">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <figcaption class="img_description">This image looks super neat.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this.

```css
.desktop-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img_description {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;  
  color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .7s, visibility .7s;
  right:0;
}
.desktop-image:hover .img_description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="images" class="misma">
  <div class="desktop-image">    
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      <p class="img_description">This image looks super neat.</p>    
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-image-misma">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default  `div` tag has a default display property `display: block`

In your code 
`<div class="desktop-image">` div appear full width of the display

set a `width:` and a `min-height:` property to solve the problem

```
.desktop-image {
   position: relative;
   width: 200px; /*new*/
   height: 200px; /*new*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS property `clear: both` to the div with the class `desktop-image`.

Answer (score -1):

Specify the width of the .desktop-image class in percentage like `.desktop-image{width:70%;}` or whatever percentage suit the page design.

By doing that image will remain in this .desktop-image div.